# Can't install Ubuntu 18.04. Failed to load ldlinux.c32

Tags: 18.04, system-installation

I've not been able to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my PC. I downloaded the ISO file from and put it on a USB through Rufus, after it fails with win32 but unfortunately I had the same result. "Failed to load ldlinux.c32". I don't know how to solve this.

pdt: Despite the PC specifications says the manufacter is HP, this PC is Asus.

PC Specifications:

[image: PC Specifications]

Error:

[image: Error image]

Comment: Did you verify your ISO download was perfect?  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and then your write to media was flawless? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck   I've seen that message on a bad install media (ie. ISO or write to thumb-drive was faulty), which may not be your issue, but it's what I'd check first (ie. the easy checks, esp. media check)

Comment: The ISO file you use to create a LiveUSB should be checked for download errors using the steps at https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 . . If the issue persists, just for testing, try installing version 19.10 of Ubuntu MATE https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/ then advise the result by adding that into your question with [edit].

Comment: I just had this issue on a *non-Ubuntu* 18.04 Ubuntu-based system; the issue can occur (applies to me case) because the ISO is of a different type to that which is expected by the writing software. I assumed (without checking) the non-Ubuntu would be the same type of ISO as is used by Ubuntu, alas nope - thus my write method was inappropriate. ISO files can be of many types, and write method may need variation depending on type of file.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the hash value of your image using [Hash Checker](https://hashchecker.net/) or [Hash tab](http://implbits.com/products/hashtab/) with these values

http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/MD5SUMS.

If hashes match then your image is fine and you might want to use the [Universal USB Installer](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) instead of Rufus.

In Rufus Make sure to Check the Correct Target System settings ( BIOS or UEFI ) and Partition Scheme ( MBR or GPT ).

To Create A USB Bootable stick on:

[Windows](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0)

[MacOS](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#0)

[Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0)

Answer (score 0):

Repair is easy.

First you must make ISO CD. Than make ISO USB. Open any file manager and copy directory slax\boot from CD to USB. Done. USB is functional.

Answer (score 0):

Switch Rufus to FAT16 or "FAT". I didn't believe it either, but it worked!